# How to get a field value from a packet layer if the field name is a string variable?

Tags: python, layer, scapy, packet, packet-sniffers

I have `layer` and `field` as variables. How can I get the field value?

```py
#packet is just a sniff() packet

layer = "IP"
field = "src"

# I need something like
fieldValue = packet[layer].field

# or
fieldValue = packet[layer].getfieldval(field)


print("Layer: ", layer, " Field: ", field, " Value: ", fieldValue)
#Output- Layer: IP Field: src Value: 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that we are sniffing packets with scapy and want to look at the values inside. Much of this is a matter of using the [scapy documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to find what attributes each layer has. You can also do this in your python/scapy interpreter with `dir(packet)` to see what attributes and methods it has. For example:

```py
>>> dir(packet)
...
 'show',
 'show2',
 'show_indent',
 'show_summary',
 'sniffed_on',
 'sprintf',
 'src',
...
```

To dynamically get the source attribute from the packet, we need to use [getattr function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), which can get both methods and attributes from an object.

```py
# Required if you are not using the scapy interpreter
from scapy.all import sniff, IP

layer = "IP"
field = "src"

# Sniff 4 packets, filtering for packets with an IP layer
packet_list = sniff(filter="ip", count=4)
# Choose first packet arbitrarily
packet0 = packet_list[0]
# We can get the attribute reflexively because python allows it
field_value = getattr(packet0[layer], field)

# Print this information
print("Layer: ", layer, " Field: ", field, " Value: ", field_value)
---
> Layer:  IP  Field:  src  Value:  192.168.1.246
```

Comment: I made a mistake with `packet_list` being where `packet0` should have been. I fixed that, so it should run. Please keep in mind that on *nix, you need to run python/scapy as sudo to capture traffic.

Comment: @Cabbo I saw your edit (and appreciate it), but in my testing, it does not seem necessary to separate out `IP` from the scapy.all. If there's more context to the fix, by all means fix it.